# PHP comparing number fields not giving correct output

Tags: php, wordpress, comparison, advanced-custom-fields

I have two meta fields in Wordpress (ACF) that track the score of our soccer games. It's a group field with a name of 'score' with two number fields in it, 'bucs' (that's us, the Bucs) and 'opp' for our opponent.

I am able to assign the variables and display them easy enough with:

```
$score = get_field('score');
    $bucsscore = $score['bucs'];
    $oppscore  = $score['opp'];

echo $bucsscore;

echo $oppscore;
```

Now my goal is to assign a class to a div based on the game outcome: win, lose, tie.  I am trying to get this class by simply comparing the two scores.

What I have so far gives me inconsistent results on every game.  Sometimes a 0 - 0 score says we lost. If we win 1 - 0 it says we tie. If we tie 1 - 1 it says we won.

```
<?php if($bucscore === $oppscore) { echo 'tie-game'; } elseif ($bucscore < $oppscore) { echo 'lost-game'; } elseif ($bucscore > $oppscore) { echo 'won-game'; }?>
```

I have tested the '===' with '=' and '==' and still get the same inconsistency. I am thinking I can reduce the amount of code if I could create a variable that gave me the class based on the comparison but I am stuck here for now.

Comment: `$bucsscore` isn't `$bucscore`. Voting to close as caused by a typo, unless you can show you've still got some kind of issue after correcting that. Always double-check your work carefully, and use debugging techniques such as var_dump() to show you what's in your variables (sensible use of which would no doubt have revealed that `$bucscore` was empty). Also some IDEs with PHP support/plugins can warn you about undefined variables before you even run the code.

Comment: In fact you should also be getting a warning about this right there in the output anyway: https://3v4l.org/S1HWE . If you aren't, it suggests that maybe PHP warnings/errors are switched off (which shouldn't ever be the case in a dev/test environment), or that they're logged to a file (likely in a live environment) but you didn't go and look there, or you simply somehow ignored this info anyway, or perhaps you're running an old unsupported version of PHP which only produces a Notice instead of a Warning (and these may also be switched off) - in which case, it's time to upgrade!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, it seems there's a typo in the variable name $bucscore. It should be $bucsscore.

```
if ($bucsscore === $oppscore) {
    echo 'tie-game';
} elseif ($bucsscore < $oppscore) {
    echo 'lost-game';
} elseif ($bucsscore > $oppscore) {
    echo 'won-game';
}
```

Comment: Problems caused by typos can just be closed with that specific closure reason. They don't need answering (as the solution to a trivial typing error is rarely of use to anyone else). See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic for details

Answer (score 1):

This code works fine for me when just assigning numbers to the vars. Maybe there's something wonky with how the data is coming from ACF?

Try a `var_dump` to see what actual datatypes you're getting from ACF:

```php
echo var_dump($bucscore);

echo var_dump($oppscore);
```